# Oracle/plsql Pivot - Aggr the date in table grid

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate

I would like to aggr the date to clean up the grid or pivot and not have duplicate dates.

results:

| rec_dt | A | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 01/01/21 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 01/01/21 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

desired results:

| rec_dt | A | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 1 | 2 | 5 |

```
Oracle 

select * from
(
 select rec_dt, type
  from tb1
   where trunc(rec_dt, 'mm') = add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -0)
     and type in (a, b, c)
)
pivot(
       count(type)
       for type in (a, b, c)
     ) order by rec
```

Comment: The `pivot` doesn't produce the result you want, because you are keeping `rec_dt` in the subquery. Remove it and you will see your desired output. But there are other odd things; for example, what is the point of adding zero (`-0`) months to a date?

Comment: add_months with a -0 is current month, -1 is previous month. If I remove the rec_dt it only give results with no dates to tie back.

Comment: Actually - I see; you think rec_dt is the same, and you **do** want to keep it. Fine; in the middle query, don't select `rec_dt`; select `trunc(rec_dt, 'mm') as rec_dt`. You are getting three rows in your output. likely, because `rec_dt` has non-zero (and different) time-of-day in each row.

Answer (score 0):

How about simple aggregation? Sample data in lines #1 - 5; query that does the job begins at line #6.

```
SQL> with test (rec_dt, a, b, c) as
  2    (select date '2021-01-01', 1, 0, 0 from dual union all
  3     select date '2021-01-01', 0, 2, 0 from dual union all
  4     select date '2021-01-01', 0, 0, 5 from dual
  5    )
  6  select rec_dt,
  7    sum(a) as a,
  8    sum(b) as b,
  9    sum(c) as c
 10  from test
 11  group by rec_dt;

REC_DT              A          B          C
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2021-01-01          1          2          5

SQL>
```

Comment: I can use DECODE all day but that was not what the question is asking. I think for my solution its a no or the actual solution. Also that is not simple to create 30-31 days, month over month.

Comment: "Sample data" means what it says; if you provided CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements, I wouldn't have to type lines #1 - 5 myself but use what you provided. As you did not ... well, I typed it myself. You already have that in your table, so you'd run query that begins at line #6.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like this:

```
select * from
(
 select trunc(rec_dt, 'mm') as rec_dt, type    --  NOTICE THE CHANGE HERE
  from tb1
   where trunc(rec_dt, 'mm') = add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -0)
     and type in (a, b, c)
)
pivot(
       count(*)           -- SAME AS count(type)
       for type in (a, b, c)
     ) order by rec   --  DO YOU MEAN order by rec_dt?
```